# Program running from visual studio but not from exe

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, include

i have a program written in c++ in visual studio 2012. When i run it from inside visual studio all fine. When i run the .exe in debug it just stops at some point of my program (the only way to find out is to put std::cout at all major points so i thought of asking here first). Since my program runs from inside visual studio i guess the problem is with the includes of open cv. I have put all .dll and .lib files that are in my main folder ....../myprogram1//myprogram1 in ....../myprogram1/debug too. Anything else that might be wrong? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you using input files (classifier or sth)? Maybe the relative pathes arent right?

Comment: The only thing i am using is include of the header files and in linker the .lib files that i have moved to debug folder with .exe among the dll's.

Comment: one idea is to try to put a message box or an infinite loop or something at the beginning of  `int main()` and then attach to the process and see what's wrong.

Comment: Can you run the application from terminal (cmd) and tell us what kind of error appears on crash?

Comment: Check the debugging parameters of your exe (Configuration properties -> Debugging). Try to set the working directory to `$(OutDir)` so the running from folder and from VS won't be differ and you may find the bug.

Comment: What exactly is $(OutDir)? I just put it there like that inthe place of $projectDir?